# ubuntu20.04,s says "No WiFi adapter found"，What specific version of driver needs to be installed

Tags: drivers, 20.04

intput `lspci` | grep -i net shows:

```
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device c852,HP Laptop computer.
```

ubuntu20.04,s says "No WiFi adapter found" when I go to settings. what should I do/What specific version of driver needs to be installed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Add the output from ` inxi -Fxz ` to the question And likely you need https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89/tree/main if Realtek 8852AE, 8852BE, and 8852CE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Network controller driver of RTL8852ce does not work on 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475717/network-controller-driver-of-rtl8852ce-does-not-work-on-20-04)